# Pow inside a for loop, not showing value

Tags: c, for-loop, pow

So I wrote this code to find the relative error between an estimate of PI and a fixed theoretical value (3.14159). But whenever I run the program, I get this in the command line: "After 5 terms pi is approximately -1.#INF00", and the same for the relative error value.  I'm not sure what's wrong

```
int main(void)
{

float i, n, error;
float term = 0;


printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
scanf("%f", &n);

 for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
 {
     term=term + pow(-1.0, i+1)/(i*i);
 }

error=fabs(term-3.141593)/(3.141593);

printf("The actual value of pi is %f\n", 3.141593);
printf("After %0.0f terms pi is apporximately %f\n", n, term);
printf("The relative error is %f %", error);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Is this c# or c? What have you tried/researched?

Comment: In the very first step of your `for` loop, when `i = 0`, you divide by zero. That's usually a bad choice.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, accidentally posted before I could put the code.

Comment: Hey @nemetroid, I just did that, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: And in your last `printf`, you need to escape the percentage sign to print a `%`, i.e, use `%%` instead of `%` to print a single `%`.

Comment: Side note: `i` and `n` should be `int`s

Comment: Did you include <math.h>?